# How to change index method in my controller to be more DRY

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm a Rails beginner and I learn that I always must try to be more DRY.

I'm have a comment system associated to my content model, and I load my comment with ajax on page scroll.

In my view I have:

```
 %section.article-comments{'data-url' => content_comments_path(@content)}
```

and in my routes.rb file I have the route

```
resources :contents,      only: :index do
    resources :comments, only: :index
  end
```

My comment controller of course is

```
def index
 @content  = Content.find(params[:content_id])
 @comments = @content.comments
 render ...
end
```

Now I want to add comments also to videos and gallery.

So I need to add a route for every resource and I need a gallery_index and a video_index.

Content, video and gallery index method in comment controlelr are repeated, and I cannot understand how can I be more DRY.

Answer (score 0):

All your controllers presumably inherit from ApplicationController:

```
class CommentsController < ApplicationController
```

If you find yourself with a lot of repetition in any of the controller methods you could define it in `ApplicationController` instead, with maybe some specific processing in each controller.

For example:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  def index
    ...some common processing...
    specific_index_processing
  end

  private

  def specific_index_processing
    # empty method; will be overridden by each controller as required
  end
end

class CommentsController < ApplicationController
  private

  def specific_index_processing
    ...specific procesing for the comments index method...
  end
end
```

And of course, if one of your controllers needs to be completely different from this common approach you can always just override the entire index method.